# Removing 'Counter' from Dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I am using the `Counter` class in Python to count the number of words in a key of a large python dictionary. I am creating a new dictionary with the keys being incremented numbers and the values being the return of the counter function. This is what my new dictionary looks like:

```
TP = {1:Counter({u'x':1, u'b':1, u'H':3}),2:Counter({u'j':1, u'm':4, u'e':2})...}
```

What I want to do, if possible, is remove the `Counter` and the parentheses ( and ) so that my dictionary looks like:

```
TP = {1:{u'x':1, u'b':1, u'H':3}, 2:{u'j':1, u'm':4, u'e':2}...}
```

If that's not possible, can someone please tell me how to access the nested dictionaries inside the ()? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any point of doing this, `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` and supports all of it's methods so you should have no problems leaving it as is, although just for the sake of this question I will convert it back to a normal `dict`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tp = {1:Counter({u'x':1, u'b':1, u'H':3}),2:Counter({u'j':1, u'm':4, u'e':2})}
>>> dict((k, dict(v)) for k, v in tp.iteritems())
{1: {u'x': 1, u'b': 1, u'H': 3}, 2: {u'e': 2, u'j': 1, u'm': 4}}
```

For Python 2.7+ (as suggested by @Blender)

```
{k: dict(v) for k, v in tp.iteritems()}
```

Iterating through subdictionaries eg:

```
for w, c in tp[1].iteritems():
    print w, c
```

Comment: Or with a dictionary comprehension: `{k: dict(v) for k, v in tp.iteritems()}`

Comment: @Blender I was keeping it cross compatible but I will also add that in as an option :)

Comment: The point of it is I don't want each individual returned word as a key, which is the standard return of the counter function. But thanks for the solution! Also, I would be happy enough to leave it as it is, but how do I access the keys and count values inside the parentheses?

Comment: @adohertyd Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @adohertyd Something like `d[1][u'b']`

Comment: @jamylak I mean if I wanted to access an inner dict in a standard dict I would say `for x in dict[key][subkey]` or something like that. I need to be able to access each word and count element in the dict

Comment: @adohertyd Ah, `for w, c in d[key].iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a pretty print method.

This is a method:

```
def pprint_counter(c):
    for k, v in c.items():
        l=[u'{}:{}'.format(ks,vs) for ks,vs in v.items()]
        print '{:4}: {}'.format(k, ' '.join(l))
```

Now test with your example:

```
tp = {1:Counter({u'x':1, u'b':1, u'H':3}),2:Counter({u'j':1, u'm':4, u'e':2})}
pprint_counter(tp)
```

Prints:

```
   1: x:1 b:1 H:3
   2: m:4 j:1 e:2
```

Now access the sub element 'x':

```
tp[1]['x']=123
pprint_counter(tp)
```

Prints:

```
   1: x:123 b:1 H:3
   2: m:4 j:1 e:2
```

So the individual elements you access by subscripting directly `tp[1]['x'] and the formating you desire -- just add code.