# Mapping/Counter, Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, count

I am new to counter and mapping function. I am writing a function that takes in a string and counts the different words and outputs in a dictionary the words and how many times they show up.

I have some questions around the map and counter functions. I know my following code works, but am not confident I truly I understand I need to assign my input string to "strs" and use that in the map function.

I also am not sure how to print the dictionary without the word "counter":

```
def wordCount(inputString):

    from collections import Counter
    strs = inputString
    c = Counter(map(str.lower,strs.split()))
    print c

inputString = 'I like pizza, beer, and more pizza'
wordCount(inputString)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing 'Counter' from Dictionary python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731633/removing-counter-from-dictionary-python)

Comment: fixed the printing issue, but not sure on the strs and the map function I have. why do i need the str and strs? i get an error when I remove

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Counter.items()` which returns a list of `(element, count)` tuples and iterating over that list and printing each element.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put the input string in `strs` , I believe it does not give any benefit.

Also, to print the Counter as a dictionary , without the `Counter` , use `dict(counter)` , Example -

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x= Counter(l)
>>> print(dict(x))
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1}
```

Demo with your example -

```
>>> def wordCount(inputString):
...     from collections import Counter
...     c = Counter(map(str.lower,inputString.split()))
...     print(dict(c))
...
>>> inputString = 'I like pizza, beer, and more pizza'
>>> wordCount(inputString)
{'more': 1, 'pizza,': 1, 'like': 1, 'i': 1, 'pizza': 1, 'and': 1, 'beer,': 1}
```

Comment: the print worked, but i dont think your method works for strings - it counts each individual letter now word.

Comment: @madman it depends on how the counter was created , converting to dict() would not change the contents of the counter , please note above is just an example , the main part is just the dict() part , you do not need to change how you are creating the counter

Comment: @madman please check latest update, I added an demo with your example.

Comment: Why do you keep converting the counter to a dictionary?

Comment: Because that is the question? - *I also am not sure how to print the dictionary without the word "counter"*

Answer (score -1):

This is an other way to do it:

```
words = 'I like pizza, beer, and more pizza'.split()
d = {}
for word in words:
    word = word.strip(',')
    d[word] = d.get(word, 0) +1
print d
```

Output:

```
{'and': 1, 'like': 1, 'I': 1, 'beer': 1, 'pizza': 2, 'more': 1}
```

I removed the commas, assuming you want to count the words without the commas.